# Squaring a variable in Two-ways fixed effect

Tags: p-value, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, causality

I am studying the effect of renewable energy on electricity prices. I am running a two-way fixed effects estimation on the model, with 23 countries from 2007-2016.

$$price.kwh_{it}  = \beta_1Perc.RE.con_{it} + \beta_3heating.days_{it}$$

Perc.RE.con is in share of renewable energy in gross final energy consumption.he variable $heating.days$ is to control for consumption.  I assume that that as the share of renewables increase the price would increase, but I do not find any significance.

I assume that the effect $perc.RE.con$ is non-linear on the price.kwh. At some point it would turn around, så i run:

$$price.kwh_{it}  = \beta_1Perc.RE.con_{it} + \beta_2Perc.RE.con_{it}^2 + \beta_3heating.days_{it}$$

I do get significance in $\hat{\beta}_2<0$ but not in $\hat{\beta}_1>0$.

Qeustions:

1. How can i interpret my result?
2. Is it even possible to include a squared variable in panel data?
3. If i calculate the turning point, is that the average turning point for all the countries? (If calculate the turning point i get a result of 24 %)